# Wave equation from linear Euler equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

The linear Euler equations for pressure $p = p_0 + p_a$, density $\rho = \rho_0 + \rho_a$, and velocity field $\mathbf{v}$ are
\begin{gather}
\frac{\partial\rho_a}{\partial t} + \rho_0\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v} = 0 \\
\rho_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial t} + \nabla p = \mathbf{0}.
\end{gather}

By taking the gradient of the first equation, and substituting the expression for $\nabla p$ from the second equation (while also using $p_a = c^2\rho_a$), I find that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial t} = c^2\nabla^2\mathbf{v}.
\end{align}

However, [this text](http://books.google.com.sa/books?id=D8GqhULfKfAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=introduction%20to%20acoustics&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GoHSUer6PMmRswbqtoHQDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (pages 17-18) says that my wave equation form only holds when $\nabla\times\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$.  In general, it states, only 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}\right)}{\partial t} = c^2\nabla^2\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}\right)
\end{align}
holds.  What then did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}) \neq \nabla^2 \mathbf{v}$.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this was the problem.